# How do I remove the side padding in the following case?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a Single page website creating angular. I am using bootstrap as my CSS agent. I have built this on top of bootstrap's starter template. However, I am facing some issues with side margins. Here's my part code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table style="width: 100%;" class="table" >
        <thead>
            <th style="width: 20%;">Name</th>
            <th style="width: 25%;">Action</th>
            <th style="width: 55%;">Description</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="text-align: left;">
            <tr ng-repeat="a in actionlist | orderBy:'sortname'">
                <td><span style="color: blue;">{{a.name}}</span></td>
                <td> {{a.actionname}} </td>
                <td> {{a.description}} </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And my extra CSS apart from the usual bootstrap.css is [Please ignore the navbar css]:

```
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.starter-template {
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

section.container {
  background-color: green !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  section.container {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .navbar-header .collapse, .navbar-toggle {
        display:block !important;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        float:none;
    }
}
```

I have made a makeshift fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/8kkb1hej/ where I have added necessary elements from `index.html` too to reproduce the problem. I have given a yellow background to the section in question. As you will be able to see in the fiddle, The table is inside the section but it is having padding on left and light. I want it to stretch from end to end in the section (horizontally) i.e. there should be absolutely no space on either right or left of table inside the section. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of Bootstrap's `container` class. Bootstrap has a `row` class that cancels out the `container` class' padding.

You can do something like this:

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <!-- your stuff -->
  </div>
</section>
```

For your reference, the `container` class provides:

```
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

And the `row` class:

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8kkb1hej/1/) is your fiddle updated.

Comment: I am planning to use this to display some "non-table" stuff too. I am facing the same issue there. Will this work there? And most importantly will this keep up with my responsive requirements?

Comment: @ashhem Yes to your first question, most likely yes to your second question (I don't see any reason why it wouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

The container class is centering your table.  You could remove the container class in your section and then use bootstraps columns to center the table:

```
<section>
<div class="starter-template col-md-8 col-offset-2">
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table style="width: 100%;" class="table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <th style="width: 20%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width: 25%;">Action</th>
      <th style="width: 55%;">Description</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="text-align: left;">
      <tr>
        <td>Random Data</td>
        <td>Random Data</td>
        <td>Random Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Random Data</td>
        <td>Random Data</td>
        <td>Random Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Random Data</td>
        <td>Random Data</td>
        <td>Random Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Random Data</td>
        <td>Random Data</td>
        <td>Random Data</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Steve, I actually did try working with grids but turn out, they are not fulfilling my other design requirements. So I had to drop the idea